# Are there open free USB designs?

Tags: usb, vhdl, design, quartus-ii, specifications

I want to learn USB and its hardware interface and start with a trivial design. I found some [VHDL in github for the ISP1362](https://github.com/mzakharo/usb-de2-fpga) and I wonder if that is a good starting point. I have already used Quartus to design other hardware for FPGA that I can download to the Altera FPGA:s.

Now I want to look and learn how USB and its hardware interface are designed and preferably starting with something basic and general and a specific design from a specific manufacturer (Qualcomm, Motorola, Philips...)

I found a design for ISP1362, would that be a good starting point or could you suggest something better for me to learn the USB design and specification?

My goal is to be able to formally verify the model, design and specification for real hardware, but I need to start with something basic and easy.

Comment: Which "some VHDL in github"? You do wonder if it is a good starting point, yet you are not giving any links to the object. How do we suppose to help you then? Seriously?

Comment: @AliChen I added the link which is also the first result in google if the phrase is googled. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual place to look is opencores – if you only [include FPGA-proven designs](http://opencores.org/projects?lang=0&stage=5&lic=0&fpga_proven=on) you also rule out these that only look good on paper. Your USB functionality is under the "Communication controller" category.

Formally verifying a design **is** a tough task, and I congratulate you on the choice of first looking into something basic.

I personally am not so sure that formally verifying a USB controller is the only way to go – in the end, both sides of a USB link have to cooperate, and being *correct* doesn't help you if you still can't work with the (possibly incorrect) other end (I don't even think the USB *spec* is formally proven).

However, I'd encourage you to look into [yosys](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/), whose author held a pretty interesting [talk](https://media.ccc.de/v/33c3-7922-formal_verification_of_verilog_hdl_with_yosys-smtbmc) about how to prove designs (rather than just testing it) based on induction.

---

Since the USB standards are open, you should probably just download and read the specs, too.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with USB core design indicates that the complexity of USB framework needs at least 10 men-years of seasoned RTL/VHDL designers to accomplish the logic of device-side USB, with protocol verification test bench environment and bus model. And much more for the HOST side. If you can afford to buy IP, say, DesignWare from Synopsis ($20k-$100k+), put at least a year for learning if starting from no background in USB.

The starting point is definitely the USB specifications, supplemented (or preceded) by populist classes (interpretations and books) from [MindShare](http://www.pdfdrive.com/usb-20-system-architecture-mindshare-e9287225.html). There are some other on-line tutorials/introductions, but they all are not good to learn from fresh start.

Comment: That is good to know that the specification and design is complicated. I'll try and understand the basics first.